# Как заставить Консольное приложение висеть в трее не блокируя его вводом от пользователя?

Tags: c#

У меня проблемы с внимание, так что я решил сделать напоминалку, которая будет сообщать, что заканчиваются деньги на интернете. В идеале что бы висела в трее, а при клике по ней, показывала текущий баланс. 
В общем-то все написал, но не удается сделать так, что бы при клике по иконке выдавалось уведомление. Все работает как надо, только если я создам Form и вызову его как диалог. Но по плану ничего лишнего на экране быть не должно. 
Если написать Console.Read() - то поток блокируется и иконка трея не реагирует на нажатие.

Вот код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double balance = GetBalance("vtc****11", "72******r9");
        NotifyIcon ni = new NotifyIcon();
        ni.Icon = SystemIcons.Information;
        ni.BalloonTipTitle = "Баланс интернета";
        ni.BalloonTipText = "Ваш баланс: " + balance;
        ni.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
        ni.Visible = true;
        ni.ShowBalloonTip(30000);
        ni.Click += Ni_Click;
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void Ni_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NotifyIcon ni = (NotifyIcon)sender;
        ni.BalloonTipText = "Ваш баланс: " + GetBalance("vtc****11", "72******r9");
        ni.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
        ni.Visible = true;
        ni.ShowBalloonTip(30000);
    }
```

Comment: Можно, наверное, спрятать окно. Но это какой-то костыль... Хочется нормальное решение)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем у меня получилось так(переделал свой древний проект):

```js
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int DeleteMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int nPosition, int wFlags);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);
        private static bool ConsoleVisible = false;
        private const int HIDE = 0;
        private const int SHOW = 9;
        private const int MF_BYCOMMAND = 0;
        private const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
        private static IntPtr ConsoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow();
        private static NotifyIcon TrayIcon;

        private static string icon = @"icons/icon.ico";
        private static string adress = string.Empty;

        static void ToggleWindow(bool visible)
        {
            ConsoleVisible = visible;
            ShowWindow(ConsoleWindow, visible ? SHOW : HIDE);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DeleteMenu(GetSystemMenu(GetConsoleWindow(), false), SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
            ToggleWindow(false);
            TrayIcon = new NotifyIcon();          
            TrayIcon.Icon = new Icon(icon);
            TrayIcon.Visible = true;
            TrayIcon.Click += TrayIcon_Click;

            Application.Run();
        }

        private static void TrayIcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NotifyIcon ni = (NotifyIcon)sender;
            ni.BalloonTipText = "The time is: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
            ni.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
            ni.Visible = true;
            ni.ShowBalloonTip(30000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Как я понимаю, вы спрятали окно... Только хитроумнее, чем я себе представлял) Хотелось бы верить, что есть решение элегантнее)

Comment: Может быть можно запретить завершение основного потока, пока есть дочерние? Тогда можно было бы запустить вечный цикл в дочернем и при этом основной не был бы занят....

Comment: Ладно, видимо стоит просто сделать WinForm приложение и не париться. Напихаю каких-нибудь настроек в него и сделаю кнопку - спрятать в трей....

Comment: на сколько мне известно по "человечески" спрятать консоль в трей нету возможности, а вот с винформой все вроде попроще, а так то, этот код вроде работает и уведомление показывает при клике на иконку в трее, можно туда даже менюшку с кнопокой выхода прицепить :)

Comment: C WinForm все действительно намного проще. Создал проект под WinForm добавил:
this.visible = false.